# What are the available options for org.osgi.framework.Bundle.stop(int)?

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle

The [javadoc](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html#stop(int)) doesn't say what are the available options for `org.osgi.framework.Bundle.stop(int)`.

I'd like to know what are those options and what each option does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As much as I see in the Javadoc, there are two options:

- **0:** Modifies the autostart flag of the bundle, too, so the Bundle might not be started after a framework restart
- **Bundle.STOP_TRANSIENT (1):** Does not modify the autostart flag of the bundle

Answer (score 3):

What part of the Javadoc are you missing?

```
options - The options for stoping this bundle. See STOP_TRANSIENT. 
The Framework must ignore unrecognized options.
```

Comment: I suppose this may be confusing because the JavaDoc refers to "options" plural but then only describes one option. This is simply to allow additional options to be defined in the future without breaking backwards compatibility.